# Excel Vba abbreviations [If, For, While, Select]

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know if there is some way to abbreviate lines of code, like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim A, B as Integer
    A = 0
    If A = 0 Then B = 1 Else B = 2
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

Instead of doing this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim A, B as Integer
    A = 0
    If A = 0 Then
        B = 1
    Else
        B = 2
    End if
End Sub
```

I could do this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim A, B as Integer
    A = 0
    If A = 0 Then B = 1 Else B = 2
End Sub
```

What other options i have to do something similar but with For, While, Select, etc...

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean? what you wrote works just fine. Although i would not do it as it gets annoying to modify and understand the code for other people as the code grows

Comment: A is declared as a variant when you do this.

Comment: @HarveyFrench Thanks, i just notice

Comment: `B = IIf(A = 0, 1, 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `:` to start a new line of code without starting a new line.

```
 Dim i as integer: For i = 1 to 10 : debug.print i : next i
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that *True* in VBA is equivalent to -1,this should do.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim A as Integer, B as Integer
    A = 0
    B = 2 + (A = 0)
End Sub
```

There may be more succinct methods but VBA is not renowned for sparse code lines. You may wish to investigate the [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from an answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524792/vba-for-loop-with-if-loop/31524922#31524922) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411711/using-colons-to-put-two-statements-on-the-same-line-in-visual-basic) you can lessen the overall number of lines / combine lines with a ":", like so:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim i As Long, s As Long
    For i = 1 To 10: s = s + i: Next i: MsgBox s
End Sub
```

Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test()
    Dim A as Long, B as Long
    A = 0
    B = 2
    If A = 0 Then B = 1
End Sub
```

Here is the way I would do it, you don't need an end if if there are no else's and there is only one statement.

Why would I do it this way? It's extremely easy to read which means anyone else can maintain the code.

I did notice you didn't Dim A as anything, you have to put the type for every single one, not just the last one in a list.

Also don't use integer, use long in VBA. There is loads of documentation out there on why, it's quicker for you to google "VBA Long instead of Integer" than it is for me to type it all out.